# I have a file in notepad++ with six columns, i want to add semicolon in each line like this

Tags: notepad++

Example

```
20170403 09:08  9220.6  9220.6  9220.6  9220.6
20170403 09:16  9220.65 9220.65 9202.9  9204.85
```

i want this line like below

```
20170403; 09:08;    9220.6; 9220.6; 9220.6; 9220.6
20170403; 09:16;    9220.65;    9220.65;    9202.9; 9204.85
```

Comment: Why are you not doing a simple search for the space and replacing it by a space and semicolon.

Comment: How do you define the number of spaces after the semicolons?

Comment: Solved.(search for the space and replacing it by a space and semicolon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open replace dialog (CTRL+H)
2. check "regular expression"
3. Find what: "(\d) " (note the space after ")")
4. Replace to: "$1; "
5. Press replace all

Comment: Just want to give some extra complement to this solution. Regex is super useful and is very much worth learning for anyone doing any amount of text processing.

Answer (score 0):

HYG a workaround. It will produce the required output but will take 10 iterations to run as you will replace numbers from 0 to 9 as shown below, so the same steps will be done for each number from 0 to 9.

1. In Notepad++ Press CTRL + H to replace
2. In the '*Find what*' box type the number, assume it's `0` for first run,
   and make sure to put a **space** after this number. i.e `0SPACE`.
3. In the '*Replace with*' box type the same number with a semicolon `;`
   after it, followed by a **space**. i.e `0;SPACE`.
4. Press '*Replace All*' button
5. Repeat for the next numbers 1, 2,...9.